How to assign different filters to each chart on a single dashboard in Spotfire Analyst
I'm using Spotfire analyst 14.0.2 HF-008. I have a single dashboard with different charts created. I want to use a different filtering scheme for each chart. How do I do this?

To edit what is filtered in each filtering scheme...

Go to File (not Edit)
Click "Document properties"
In the window that comes up, select the "Filtering schemes" tab
On that tab, select the checkbox "Show filtering scheme menu in filters panel"
Then, on the filters panel to the right of the screen...use drop down to select the filter scheme you want to adjust.
Then adjust the filters as needed. These adjustments will be saved in the selected filter scheme.

To change the filtering scheme for an individual chart...

Right click on an individual chart
Select properties.
Go to subsets
Select the filter scheme to be used for that chart.

